# In Blue prism button is not able to click while executing mode

Tags: blueprism, rpa

Hi I am new to blue prism

My question is:

I have button in my application after recording if i try to highlight it is working fine but while executing it is not able to click the button and i am not getting any error.

Answer (score 2):

If you provide a screenshot of the attribute list in your application modeler, it might be easier to provide an accurate answer. However, for now, I can give you some pointers:

For most applications the following can be unticked:

1. any elements with a blank value
2. all 'Parent' attributes unless
   required to make the element a unique match
3. the 'Visible' and 'Enabled' attributes usually have no impact if left ticked or unticked, so can often be unticked
4. With any attributes which may not be persistent and could be prone to changing — i.e. element count, application’s URL, etc.—, it is recommended to untick them or, if required in your process, use the wildcard match type to dynamically build the corresponding values which will allow easy identification.

> To speed up finding the elements, it is recommended that the Match Index attribute be used when possible. This works by stopping Blue Prism from trawling through the application model for duplicate elements once one matching element is found.

It is also recommended to add a wait stage at the start of each action. This will handle system latency and provide a correct path for your process:

[image]

The above are some pointers that I have consolidated for your ease. However, all the help you need can be found on the Blue Prism portal itself : [Blue Prism Documentation](https://portal.blueprism.com/documents/standard)

Hope this helps.. Good luck!