# Blue Prism: Object not found when ran using Control Center, but runs without issue through Process Studio

Tags: blueprism

During my process there is a drop-down html element that I have spied and set correctly. I run through the Object and Process studio without any issues. Once the same process is ran through the Control Room the element throws and error that it cannot be found.

I have tried multiple different configurations without any luck and the element is still found without issue when ran manually. I even checked by signing into the VM having it error and on the second retry had the VM up; at this stage the element was found without issue. It seems to only be when the bot is running and the screen is not up. No other elements give this issue and the next step is the same dropdown, but for a stop time not start.

Any help would be appreciated!

I have added pics of the START[SPIED - START](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4MDl.png) and END[SPIED - END](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFtyL.png) spied configs,the [Navigation Stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNFru.png), and the process correctly running in the Object Studio [OB Studio correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByXpX.png).

Thank you!

For the person who down-voted this item...[Configs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4zv8.png) here are my two days of config changes and research that I tried on my own before asking for help. This is my 5th automation that I have put into deployment without help, so thank you for down-voting someone trying to get help where they are stuck.

Comment: Something had been posted before that was close: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352692/in-blue-prism-button-is-not-able-to-click-while-executing-mode

Comment: Can you please provide the exact text of the error you're seeing?

Comment: ERROR: Internal: Failed to perform Step 1 In Navigation Stage "START" on page "W: Filter Time - 7PM" - No elements match the supplied query terms.

Comment: I just added a picture of the navigation page in question. As noted this runs fine when I run in the process and object studio without this error. It is only in the Control Room.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which software are you using to connect to the Runtime Resource instance?

Comment: Based on your image, you're not utilizing any intelligent waits. It's somewhat likely that the process is running extremely quickly in the Control Room and not allowing the element in question to load all the way before attempting to interact with it. In the Control Room, even at full speed, this might not occur.

Comment: I have tried multiple waits which are removed from this current image. There are also waits that I have tried up to 60 seconds after "Select start Drop" to give the page time to load with the same results.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but lack of research is not the only valid reason for downvote, unclear and not useful are also valid reasons. As for your current problem, I think it's really hard to troubleshoot. Only thing I could suggest would be to try different criteria for spying the element. Maybe uncheck match index and try something like ancestor count and/or class name

Comment: Thank you Jerry. That's what I have tried since I ran into the issue when running through the control room. I have tried multiple configurations, respied the element, added waits, added intelligent waits with the same outcome. When I find a configuration that works I run it through the object studio, then the process studio without issues. Once it is ran through the CR it errors out, so I added a retry and accessed the VM on the second try AFTER the error and it finds the element without the error and completes. It has something to do with eh screen visibility, but no other element errors out.

Comment: @James.P I actually overlooked something: your wait should happen **before** you click, otherwise it doesn't make any sense. That said, if you believe this is a visibility issue, then you might want to *activate application* before performing the click. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cowTp.png) is how I typically make the clicks (if the application is already activated, then it usually errors out, hence the recover/resume). Note: Activate application is usually applied to a window element (not a button, label, or such)

Comment: Also, try to keep the actions separate: one for click on start start, one for click on end

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is most likely connected with the fact that processes run in the control room are executed much faster than in studio and your webpage might not be loaded on time (that would explain why it works after retry).

Best practice approach would be to add a dynamic wait stage after attach and use “Parent Document Loaded” option on the element you want to interact with. It will wait for the page to be loaded and then check exist for the element. I would also suggest splitting your action into two, first to set start date and second for end date.